# Resample multiindex and add column to original df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiindex DF with `Name` and `Date` (datetime) as indexes. I'm attempting to downsample the `value` column from daily to weekly and add the resulted column back to the df (with ffilled values).
I can successfully resample but whenever I try to create a new column, I only get NaNs, even when using reindex.

```
df.groupby('Name').value.resample('W-MON', level='Date').max()
```

DF structure:

```
                     value
Name    Date
ALFA    2019-11-22   123
        2019-11-23   777
BETA    2019-11-21   456
        2019-11-22   567
```

Comment: Can you share the DataFrame in a format that makes it easy for other people to use?

Answer (score 0):

In my project (too large to post) the multiindex levels were reversed. The solution was simple enough:

```
df.reorder_levels(['Name', 'Date'])
```